# Adding traps to test script running in Travis CI

Tags: bash, travis-ci, bash-trap

I have a test script that gets called in `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
  - ./test.sh
```

This test script is run whenever a commit is pushed to a repository. This is a `bash` script in which I create a temporary directory, add a trap to remove that directory when the script completes, and do some work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
set -o errexit

TMPDIR=$(mktemp --directory --tmpdir=${HOME})

trap 'rm -rf "${TMPDIR}"' EXIT

# ...some work...
```

What causes problems is that `trap` call.

When the tests pass, the script exits successfully with status code `0`. The `EXIT` trap is triggered, which begins an attempt to delete `${TMPDIR}`.

This attempt fails due to permissions errors, e.g.:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/travis/tmp.uaFEDOAgQt/.../log/error.log’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/travis/tmp.uaFEDOAgQt/.../log/access.log’: Permission denied
The command "./test.sh" exited with 1.
```

The script runs processes as the Travis environment user. Those processes create these (log) files. Those processes are not run as other users. Since the processes are started by the Travis user, those directories must be owned by the Travis user, and so it should be possible to remove them. However, they cannot be removed.

This is not an issue if I run the test script locally. This only occurs as an issue within the Travis CI build environment.

One solution is to disable the trap. What might be other solutions? Can I add `sudo` to a command run within a (`trusty`) Travis environment, without the script being prompted for a password? I suppose a `sudo` call should override permissions complaints, but it's not clear why that should be an error in the first place.

Comment: Can you just allow the travis environment user the permission to delete the file? Ie. `chown` or `chmod 777`